# Incorporating features that are always 0 given the value of another feature into a decision tree?

Tags: classification, cart, feature-engineering

If I'm building a decision tree model, what is the best way to incorporate features that are always 0 given the value of another feature?

For example, imagine I'm predicting whether or not someone has high blood pressure, and two of the many features I have are gender and whether or not the person has uterine cancer.  Clearly if gender is male, then uterine cancer has to be 0 because men cannot get uterine cancer.  I'm fairly positive this can be done with interaction terms, but decision trees cannot utilize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decision trees (e.g. CART) should not be affected.

In the male branch of the tree, the cancer variable would be always 0. Therefore, it has 0 statistical power. And the tree will not learn any splits based on the cancer variable.

Comment: No splits in the male branch, or no splits in both the male and the female branch?

Comment: Hey @BrandonSherman, just the male branch. The cancer variable has predictive power in the female branch, so there will be a split on the cancer variable if your max depth allows it.

Comment: Ah okay.  So it does the split automatically, so there's no need to manually create an interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, your Gender and Cancer factors are neither crossed nor nested. If they were nested, then you could just specify the interaction term, but I am not sure whether it will work correctly in this case.

Therefore, I think the best way to avoid confusion is to introduce a new factor Gender_Cancer with 3 levels: "M_No", "F_Yes", "F_No". Then in order to test the effect of gender, you specify the contrast as "M_No vs F_No". To test the effect of Cancer, the contrast is: "F_Yes vs F_No".

Comment: (+1) This is a good answer because it takes advantage of an intrinsic ability of decision trees to study interactions. Besides, it's one less feature to try splits, so might speed up calculations a bit. Also, it's useful because splits on sex variables might not be near the root node.